# Xamarin UI Test iOS on Windows

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I need testing UI of my Xamarin application under iOS. I use the `Xamarin.UITest | CrossPlatform` on Visual Studio (windows 10) for this. Yesterday i found the solution of Android and now need it for iOS simulator. My PC is connected to mac, and I can start application on local machine in simulator. But I can't start UI test :

```
public class AppInitializer
{
    public static IApp StartApp(Platform platform)
    {
        if (platform == Platform.Android)
        {
            return ConfigureApp
                .Android
                .ApkFile(@"D:\..MyApp.apk")
                .StartApp();
        }

        return ConfigureApp
            .iOS
            .AppBundle(@"D:\..MyApp.iOS")
            .StartApp();
    }
}
```

> Message: SetUp : System.Exception : iOS tests are not supported on
>   Windows.

[image]

iOS Simulator Work correct, why I can't start UI.Test ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment it's not possible to run UITest for iOS app on Windows, you need to do it on your macOS machine.

Source: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/testing-on-devices/ios/

You can vote on this feature here: https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-platform-suggestions/suggestions/6805940-enable-running-xamarin-uitest-on-ios-device-from-v

Comment: one more thing.. Can I Start xamarin ui test on my MAC with out source code ? Just create 1 Xamarin.UI test project and set the path to building *.ios.ioa file ?

Comment: as far as I'm aware you need to add this project to the solution with mobile projects. Maybe it'd possible to just reference dll produced by mobile apps, but you'd need to try it